# Swift playgrounds ios 10 text to speech command code

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I'm using swift playgrounds on iOS iPad to create a text to speech command. Below is the code.

```
import AVFoundation
let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance (string: "Say     
Hello")
utterance.rate = 1
synthesizer.speak(utterance:   
AVSpeechUtterance)
```

//when I hit "run my code". I get the error message "Attempt to evaluate editor placeholder"
I don't know what this error means. Hopefully someone can help. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`utterance: AVSpeechUtterance` is just an editor placeholder that tells you what you should put there:

```
synthesizer.speak(utterance: AVSpeechUtterance)
```

You need to call it passing it the utterance object you created:

```
synthesizer.speak(utterance)
```

---

To get it to speak, you need a few more lines.  Here is the complete code:

```
import AVFoundation
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Say Hello")

utterance.rate = 0.5

synthesizer.speak(utterance)
```

Comment: I changed it to synthesizer.speak(utterance) like you said and the error went away. Thanks.

Comment: But it still didn't speak the text "say hello"

Comment: See updated answer.  You need a few more lines of code.